# Limit of Fréchet differentiable functions

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

If I have a sequence of Fréchet differentiable functions, under what conditions can I prove that the limit is Fréchet differentiable?
For example, suppose that I have $f:\ell^p(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by an expression $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x_k)$ when $f_k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is  Fréchet differentiable. Then how I can prove that $Df(x)(d)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Df_k(x_k)(d_k)$?

Comment: One sufficient condition would be some uniformity condition like for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $k$, if $|d| < \delta$ then $|f_k(x_k+d)-f_k(x_k)-f_k'(x_k)d | \le \epsilon |d|$.

Comment: Can you prove it please?

Comment: I think you can do it, remember that $d \in l_q$.

Comment: I don't know why that condition works.

Comment: I may have been a little optimistic.

Comment: I posted an unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following (strong) condition:  Suppose there is some $B \in l_q$ and for any $\epsilon> 0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that for any $k$ and for any $|d| < \delta$ we have
$|f_k(x_k+d)-f_x(x_k)-f_k(x_k)d| \le \epsilon |B_k||d|$.

Choose $x \in l_p, d \in l_q$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose
$\|d\|_q < \delta$ (in particular, $|d_k| < \delta$).

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x+d)-f(x)-\sum_k f_k'(x_k)d_k | &\le& \sum_k |f_k(x_k+d_k)-f_k(x_k)-f_k'(x_k)d_k | \\
&\le & \sum_k \epsilon |B_k||d_k| \\
&=& \epsilon \|B\|_p \|d\|_q
\end{eqnarray}
Then $f$ is differentiable and
$Df(x)d = \sum_k f_k'(x_k)d_k$.